# Why does a variable become real when using the second argument of Dynamic?

Tags: dynamic

Version 9, on Windows 7.

Please compare these 2 very simple examples

```
Manipulate[
 x,
 Row[{Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {0, 10, 1/100}]}],
 {{x, 1}, None}
]
```

and

```
Manipulate[
 x,
 Row[{Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #) &], {0, 10, 1/100}]}],
 {{x, 1}, None}
]
```

Would you not expect them to work the same way?

But in the second case, `x` becomes real, while in the first case it remains rational as expected.

[image]

Any one knows the reasoning for this? I read about the [second argument of `Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html), but do not see something obvious. I did not read everything about it. But the above behaviour is surprising.

The fix is easy:

```
Manipulate[
 x,
 Row[{Manipulator[
    Dynamic[x, (x = Rationalize[#]) &], {0, 10, 1/100}]}],
 {{x, 1}, None}
 ]
```

I am only asking why it happens, so I can learn more.

Comment: Particularly odd that the documentation says *Dynamic[expr] is equivalent to Dynamic[expr,(expr=#)&]. *

Comment: Weeeeeeeeeeeird

Comment: Confirmed in version 7 as well.

Comment: Confirmed.  It can be reproduced with the simpler `Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #) &], {0, 1, 1/10}]`.  I am just *guessing* that this has to do with the variable being handled by the front end (not kernel), which might not be able to do computations with rationals.  This is a wild guess and I have no idea why the effect would show in this particular example.

Comment: Same with V8 on Mac

Comment: Great question, I'm struggling with this feature lately. It appears in many context. I'm going to ask similar question in the near future.

Comment: Have you ever asked WRI about this behaviour?

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry, I did not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not an answer but it's too long for a comment.  Also please remember that all the following are just **guesses**.

My first observation is that the simplified

```
Slider[Dynamic[x, (x=#)&], {0, 1, 1/10}]
```

can reproduce the problem.

We know that some variables (in particular `DynamicModule` variables) are owned by the Front End, not the Kernel, and can be directly set using GUI elements (such as `Slider`) without needing any kernel interaction.  It is reasonable to assume that the Front End is only able to do computations with machine level data types like integers and reals, but not arbitrary precision numbers or `Rational`s.  Why this might have an effect in this particular example, I do not know.

But let us take a look at what sort of box forms (which are handled by the front end) are generated for different variations of `Slider`:

**1.** First, the basic `Dynamic` with a `Real` step size:

```
Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 1, 0.1}]

Cell[BoxData[
 SliderBox[Dynamic[$CellContext`x], {0, 1, 0.1}]], "Output"]
```

This is a simple box form that maps to the input expression directly.

**2.** Now let's try a `Rational` step size:

```
Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 1, 1/10}]

Cell[BoxData[
 SliderBox[Dynamic[
   BoxForm`RemapVariable[$CellContext`x, {0, 1, Rational[1, 10]}], 
   BoxForm`RemapValue[#, $CellContext`x, {0, 1, Rational[1, 10]}]& ], 
  {0, 10, 1}]], "Output"
]
```

Here I see something new (and to me unfamiliar): `RemapValue` and `RemapVariable`.  Is this maybe used to ask the kernel to do computations?  The slider range and step size are now all integers and are remapped using a (possibly kernel evaluated function) to rationals.

**3.** Let's try `Dynamic` with a second argument and a `Rational` step size:

```
Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #) &], {0, 1, 1/10}]

Cell[BoxData[
 SliderBox[Dynamic[$CellContext`x, ($CellContext`x = #)& ], {0, 1, Rational[1, 10]}]], 
 "Output"]
```

The `RemapValue` is gone now!

---

Can we add the second argument of `Dynamic` back to the `RemapValue` version of the box form?  Note that `Dynamic` already has two arguments there, so it should be grafted onto the `RemapValue` function somehow.

Comment: It seems to me like you're right. The FE doesn't like to deal with rationals, so it turns them to reals. But in the "single agrument dynamic" case, it deals with it by changing the values of the slider to integers, and then fixing it all by tweaking the dynamic it generates. It creates a dynamic with a second argument that maps the integers to the corresponding rational, an a first argument that tells the front end to actually display the corresponding integer in the slider

Comment: They probably couldn't or didn't take the time to make a "fix" for the case at hand, when you supply your own second argument to Dynamic, that should be "mixed" with the one they generate automatically... Just more guesses

Comment: @Rojo I'm wondering why they need *two* transformations: `RemapVariable` and `RemapValue`.  I think it has to do with how `x` is set based on the slider and what the slider displays based on `x`, but experimenting too much breaks the slider permanently sometimes.

Comment: I think the same. Say the range is `{0, 1, 1/10}`. The created slider actually goes from `{0, 10}` through the integers. It has to save the `value/10` in the variable, and it has to display the `variable*10` in the "stretched" slider

Comment: FYI you can Spelunk the definitions of ``BoxForm`RemapVariable`` and ``BoxForm`RemapValue``, they are indeed kernel functions which do just what you guessed.