# Why does one of my Manipulate integer variables get turned into a real?

Tags: manipulate, bugs, variable

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I'm developing code for manipulating graphs. Spot the difference in the 2 Manipulates below:

```
Manipulate[
 {n, m},
 {{n, 10, "no of vertices"}, 1, 18, 1},
 {{m, n, "number of edges"}, n, n (n - 1)/2 , 1}
 (* using the +/-/slider for the number of edges does not generate Reals 
    but only Integers as expected *)]
```

[image: first image of Manipulate]

this first example works as expected but

```
Manipulate[
 {n, m},
 {{n, 10, "no of vertices"}, 1, 18, 1},
 {{m, n, "number of edges"}, n - 1, n (n - 1) /2, 1}
 (* using the +/-/slider for the number of edges now generates Reals 
    not Integers: what gives? *)]
```

[image: second image of Manipulate]

turns my nice integers into reals as soon as I change the number of edges.  I can turn this back into an integer when that's what I need, but I'd prefer not to.  Naturally I have a more complex task to complete but these examples are simple enough to illustrate the issue.

Version: Mathematica 9.0.1.0

Platform: Mac

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16282/12

Comment: yes, I saw that before posting my question but was a bit alarmed by it and it didn't seem obviously the same problem at first sight (I didn't realise I was using the 2nd argument to Dynamic...).  Also, Remap{Value,Variable} didn't appear on closer inspection of the Manipulates

Comment: Yes, I was checking that too.  I don't know if the underlying problem is the same in the two cases but the symptoms are very similar.

Comment: Does it deserve a bug tag or am I being over-zealous?

Comment: I don't know, it's all too unclear to me now, but the behaviour is definitely undesirable.  You could try asking support about it and let us know what they said ...  I'm trying to come up with a more fundamental example to at least figure out the difference between the two `Manipulate`s.

Comment: Good idea.  I'll post when I get a reply.

Comment: This will reproduce the problem: `x = n = 10;
Slider[Dynamic[x], {Dynamic[n], Dynamic[n + 10], 1}]
Dynamic[x]`.  It's not the whole story though because in some more complex (and slightly different) versions I tried where `n` and `x` were localized to a `DynamicModule`, the numbers were converted to real only if I change `n` to `n-1` as in your example.  If the lower bound of `Slider` is not wrapped in `Dynamic` then there's no problem.

Comment: Response (shortened):This is an example of unintended behavior in Mathematica that our developers are aware of.

There are a number of workarounds.  Simplest is to wrap a function around the appropriate bounds; instead of

    `Manipulate[m, {n, {10}}, {m, n - 1, 2 n, 1}]`

do:

    `Manipulate[Floor@m, {n, {10}}, {m, n - 1, 2 n, 1}]`

A solution can be pushed into the controller itself:

    `Manipulate[m, {n, {10}}, {{m, 9}, Dynamic[Slider[#1, {n - 1, 2 n, 1}]] &}]`

from Karl Isensee

Comment: Why don't you post this as an answer for more visibility?  It's the best answer so far.  It's okay to answer your own question on SE, and particularly encouraged in cases like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of unintended behavior in Mathematica that the developers are aware of. There are a number of workarounds.  The simplest is to wrap a function around the appropriate bounds; instead of

```
Manipulate[m, {n, {10}}, {m, n - 1, 2 n, 1}]
```

which illustrates the problem, try

```
Manipulate[Floor@m, {n, {10}}, {m, n - 1, 2 n, 1}]
```

A solution can also be pushed into the controller itself:

```
Manipulate[m, {n, {10}}, {{m, 9}, Dynamic[Slider[#1, {n - 1, 2 n, 1}]] &}]
```

Thanks for this feedback and suggestions are due to Karl Isensee.

Comment: But the bug is still now.